# Place on Google Map in "Suspended"

Tags: google-maps

I made some modify at one place in Google Maps, but are still in "Suspended" status.

How many time need to be check?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is a support related question

Answer (score 0):

Usually it takes Google few weeks (sometimes up to 4-6 weeks) to reconsider the modified place, providing that the modifications you've made are in compliance with Google Places' guidelines. If it takes longer, I'd suggest you contact their support team, to find out why is it suspended.